# `ipympl` interactive plots are not interactive, no navigation bar or buttons, in jupyter notebook in pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipympl

I am running the example on `ipympl` homepage in a jupyter notebook in pycharm:

```
%matplotlib ipympl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(3*x)
ax.plot(x, y)
```

And I am not getting interactive toolbar buttons. I have tried the following.

1. Without `ipympl` I am getting a static plot, not interactive.
2. Using `ipympl`, I am getting still a static plot, but it looks different to the one without `ipympl`.
3. Using `Qt5Agg` as backend without `ipympl`, I am not getting plots at all
4. Using `Qt5Agg` and `ipympl`, I get a poped up window for the plot, but that window is stuck, without content.

#### This is with `ipympl`:

[image: With ipympl]

#### This is without `ipympl`:

[image: Without ipympl]

#### Using `Qt5Agg` as backend without `ipympl`

```
# %matplotlib ipympl
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

[image]

#### Using `Qt5Agg` and `ipympl`

```
%matplotlib ipympl
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

[image]

In none of the cases is there interactive navigation bar or buttons. I am not sure if this is a pycharm problem, or my matplotlib versions (tried 3.4.0 3.5.0 3.8.1) or something else.

Comment: Looks like PyCharm has issues with these things: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-62665 . The posted code snippet works for me in VSCode

Comment: Thanks. I thought a lot of peple are using jupyter notebook in pycharm, in which case this would be a serious problem, right? Seems nobody cares - is this not the canonical way to work with jupyter notebook or did I miss something?

Comment: I have no idea who uses PyCharm for what I'm afraid. Jupyter notebooks are an entirely separate thing. The 'canonical' way would be through the browser interface I imagine. https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: At the link posted in the first comment, they suggest using Qt5 as the backend with PyCharm. Did you try that and get an interactive plot? (You'd leave off the `%matplotlib ipympl` in that case, too.)

Comment: @Wayne not working either; I have updated the post.

Comment: Hmmmm...the Qt without the `ipympl` looks promising but that you don't have something installed properly so that it is handled correctly and so it is just showing the Python object code in the output area. It's weird. I don't know what it could be though because you get a Qt Window to come up in the next view you show below that. Did you install ipywidgets? It may worth trying that and restart everything and try again. I'm out of my depth with both PyCharm and ipympl in the mix. If you didn't mind making things more complicated, you could install the Anaconda Distribution which includes ...

Comment: <continued> Jupyter that I think has ipywidgets installed. If you go that way, check if ipympl is installed in Jupyter you get with that. And if not run in a new notebook, `%conda install -c conda-forge ipympl` to install it, based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ipympl).